# Is WebView localStorage stored in the app cache?

Tags: storage, cache

I am writing a hybrid app (Cordova 6.5, Angular 1.5, Ionic 1.3, HTML5) that will run on Android. This kind of app works in WebView.

My app has a few images bundled with the app and most of the data will be called via HTTP and some of it will be stored in localStorage for offline mode.

I have seen that it's possible to manually write images etc. into the app cache (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), but I am not doing this myself in my app.

I am wondering what kind of data does the Android OS store in the app cache by default. I hope this does not include the html5 localStorage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app cache helps the app run faster. Every time an app loads some data (like images and so on) it gets stored in the app cache. If the user opens the app again, this data is not reloaded. It is taken from the app cache instead. This makes the app faster. App cache though does not persist and is erased every time you restart your phone.

In the localStorage though, you store things that the app will need to remember even when the phone restarts. For example what is your progress in a game, some app parameters etc.

See more about app cache [here](https://www.androidpit.com/clear-app-cache-vs-clear-app-data-difference).